# Why my WDAC policy created using Event Viewer logs based on FilePath rule isn't working?

Tags: windows-11, windows-defender, security-policy

I'm trying to understand why my WDAC policy is not letting the programs I allow-listed using Event Viewer logs, to run.

This is how I made my WDAC Policy allow list based on Event Viewer audit logs:

```
New-CIPolicy -FilePath .\EventsPolicy.xml -Audit -Level FilePath –UserPEs -UserWriteablePaths -MultiplePolicyFormat 3> .\EventsPolicyWarnings.txt
```

I only want to use FilePath because then the policy won't need to be updated when programs are updated to newer versions.

Some of the parts responsible for apps allow list from EventViewer policy:

```
<Allow ID="ID_ALLOW_A_6" FriendlyName="GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe FileRule" MinimumFileVersion="0.0.0.0" FilePath="GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" />
 <Allow ID="ID_ALLOW_A_14" FriendlyName="GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip.dll FileRule" MinimumFileVersion="0.0.0.0" FilePath="GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip.dll" />
<Allow ID="ID_ALLOW_A_11" FriendlyName="GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Mullvad VPN\resources\mullvad-daemon.exe FileRule" MinimumFileVersion="0.0.0.0" FilePath="GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Mullvad VPN\resources\mullvad-daemon.exe" />
```

after creating this policy, then I merged it with a policy I made earlier that is based on Microsoft ISG (Signed and reputable mode), and in the final policy, the result of the merge, these are the policy rules I set:

```
<Rules>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Unsigned System Integrity Policy</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:UMCI</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Inherit Default Policy</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Update Policy No Reboot</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Intelligent Security Graph Authorization</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Developer Mode Dynamic Code Trust</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Revoked Expired As Unsigned</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Required:Enforce Store Applications</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Required:WHQL</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Dynamic Code Security</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Disabled:Runtime FilePath Rule Protection</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Invalidate EAs on Reboot</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Allow Supplemental Policies</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Advanced Boot Options Menu</Option>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Option>Enabled:Unsigned System Integrity Policy</Option>
</Rule>
```

At first, I thought programs running under SYSTEM user are Kernel-mode drivers. reading the comment and answer below I realized that's not the case. what made me think like that was 1)

in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/select-types-of-rules-to-create#table-2-windows-defender-application-control-policy---file-rule-levels): next to "FilePath"

it says: "FilePath rules only apply to user mode binaries and can't be used to allow kernel mode drivers."

and 2)

When I used this to create WDAC policy allow-list based on Event Viewer logs, then only the program running as SYSTEM wasn't able to run and other programs such as 7-zip was allowed to run.

```
New-CIPolicy -FilePath .\EventsPolicy.xml -Audit -Level FileName -Fallback FilePath –UserPEs -UserWriteablePaths -MultiplePolicyFormat 3> .\EventsPolicyWarnings.txt
```

WDAC policy created using this allowed all programs that would've been blocked by WDAC, to run:

```
New-CIPolicy -FilePath .\EventsPolicy.xml -Audit -Level hash –UserPEs -UserWriteablePaths -MultiplePolicyFormat 3> .\EventsPolicyWarnings.txt
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but I do know that the things you see in the task manager running as SYSTEM aren't kernel mode device drivers.  The specific ones you show are services which is nowhere near a kernel mode device driver.  Device drivers run IN THE KERNEL which is it's own process.  They don't show up in the task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, processes running as SYSTEM are not running in kernel-mode. A short explanation is:

> All drivers run in a single kernel process along with the rest of the kernel.
>
> Process id 0 is the "idle process" and process id 4 (on XP and later) is the kernel "process".
>
> from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70772211/7411885) answer

For example, here is the kernel process which all kernel-mode drivers run under (PID 4):

[image]

---

I'm not sure without seeing your FilePath rule or how you created it, but there are plenty of reasons it might not work:

- a unique, fully qualified path rule must be generated for every file in the scanned path(s) unless using a wildcard `*`
- Wildcards can be only used at the beginning or end of a FilePath rule (not in the middle). Only one wildcard is allowed per path rule.
- If a filepath allows write permissions for any SID not in WDAC's admin list, the filepath is considered to be user-writeable. WDAC will fail the rule unless you specifically disable the `Runtime FilePath Rule Protection`
- Hash rules allow for slight changes, since the hash of a file doesn't change when the file is renamed, re-signed, timestamped, etc.
- There is currently a bug where MSIs cannot be allow listed in file path rules.

EDIT: I personally do not use file paths like `\Device\HarddiskVolume4\` since the volume number is not guaranteed. Try using `-ScanPath` to generate valid file path rules:

```
New-CIPolicy -ScanPath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip' -UserPEs -FilePath .\FilePolicy.xml -Level FilePath
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with all the information I could think of to be more clear, please let me know if there is anything I missed.

Comment: @lina Do you see logs generated by WDAC in `Microsoft-Windows-CodeIntegrity/Operational`? For example 3033 if a process fails to load a file: `Code Integrity determined that a process (\path\to\7zFM.exe) attempted to load \other\path\to\system.dll that did not meet the Enterprise signing level requirements`

Comment: Yes, but the event description is the opposite, it says a system.dll tried to load `7zfm.exe`.

`Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\explorer.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe that did not meet the Enterprise signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy (Policy ID:{f5c310f4-9b3e-4d06-a0b6-04194ab1d950}).`

Comment: I added my full WDAC policy to the question.

Comment: @lina I'm not familiar with all of the options you've specified - maybe one of them is causing you trouble? Or test out scanning for the file paths, and see if it has to fall back to using hash for any of them: `New-CIPolicy -ScanPath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip' -Audit -UserPEs -FilePath .\PathHashPolicy.xml -Level FilePath -Fallback Hash`. I don't use the `\Device\HarddiskVolumeX\ ` paths myself

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me what that comment does exactly? I'm trying to understand it but some parts of it are confusing for me. also, I wouldn't use the `\Device\HarddiskVolumeX\` either but the command i used automatically added them. i will try to remove them manually see if it changes anything.

Comment: Well, good news, I find & replaced the  \Device\HarddiskVolumeX\  with drive letters  and it worked! the policy is now working as expected, being enforced (checked in system information) and also allowing the programs whose filepath was added to the allow list in policy. so the solution is to just get rid of the `GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume4` and replace them with things like `C:` or `D:` etc. you can add the solution to your answer so i can accept it or i can post it myself so others doing this will know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a WDAC policy based on audit event logs, first you have to deploy a WDAC policy in Audit mode in order to begin the process, after that you start installing your programs and running them after installation so audit event logs will be created for each of their files, once you're done, you scan the logs and create a WDAC policy based on them.

You need to merge this policy with a base policy such as AllowMicrosoft to allow essential Windows components as well as Microsoft signed files to be allowed to run.

FilePath rules aren't really recommended because they aren't as secure as [File hash, File publisher etc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/select-types-of-rules-to-create#table-1-windows-defender-application-control-policy---policy-rule-options)

You can use the guides I've created on GitHub about Windows Defender Application Control:

https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDAC-for-Fully-Managed-Devices

And the [WDACConfig PowerShell module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig) will automate the entire process for you.

---

## WDAC policy for Fully Managed device - Variant 1

| Base policy type | Method used | Signed | Protection score 1-5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allow Microsoft / Default Windows | [WDACConfig module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig) | No | 4 |

---

- This variant helps you create and deploy a WDAC policy for fully managed device ***using only Event Viewer audit logs.***
- This scenario includes using explicit Allow rules for files and certificates/singers, anything not allowed by the policies we are going to make are automatically denied/blocked.

### Prepare a Virtual Machine

Install Hyper-V role from optional Windows features if you haven't already.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers-DisposableClientVM -All -norestart
```

Download the latest Windows `.ISO` file [from Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/), create a new VM with it, install Windows and log in. Fully update Windows and then restart to apply the updates. You can create a Hyper-V checkpoint at this point so that you can return back to this clean state later on if you need to.

### Prepare a Base policy

There are 2 types of base policies you can choose from.

1. Allow Microsoft: Allows only files and apps that are signed by Microsoft's trusted root certificate.
2. Default Windows: Allows only files and apps that come pre-installed by Windows.

#### Deploy the Allow Microsoft Prep mode base policy

```
New-WDACConfig -PrepMSFTOnlyAudit -LogSize 10MB
```

##### [Parameter Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/New-WDACConfig#new-wdacconfig--prepmsftonlyaudit)

#### Deploy the Default Windows Prep mode base policy

```
New-WDACConfig -PrepDefaultWindowsAudit -LogSize 10MB
```

##### [Parameter Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/New-WDACConfig#new-wdacconfig--prepdefaultwindowsaudit)

Depending on whichever of the option you choose, it deploys the base policy in audit mode. No reboot required.

### Generate Audit event logs on the system

Install all of the programs that you want to allow in the WDAC policy, on the VM. These are the programs that you want to allow to run and be installed on the target system once you've deployed the WDAC policy.

- Installing or running 3rd party non-Microsoft programs, while ***Allow Microsoft*** policy in Audit mode is deployed on the VM, generates event logs for each of the programs and their files.
- Installing or running any program that doesn't come pre-installed by default with Windows, while **Default Windows** policy in Audit mode is deployed on the VM, generates event logs for each of the programs and their files.

These event logs are exactly what we need to identify and create Allow rules for the detected files.

Only files that are executed during Prep mode phase generate event logs, so by simply installing a program using its installer, we can't trigger event log generation for each of the components and executables that each program has. So, after installing the programs, run them, use them a bit as you normally would so that all of the programs' components are executed and event logs generated for them.

### Generate Supplemental policy from the Audit event logs

#### If you chose the Allow Microsoft path

```
New-WDACConfig -MakePolicyFromAuditLogs -BasePolicyType 'Allow Microsoft Base' -NoDeletedFiles
```

##### [Parameter Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/New-WDACConfig#new-wdacconfig--makepolicyfromauditlogs)

#### If you chose the Default Windows path

```
New-WDACConfig -MakePolicyFromAuditLogs -BasePolicyType 'Default Windows Base' -NoDeletedFiles
```

##### [Parameter Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/New-WDACConfig#new-wdacconfig--makepolicyfromauditlogs)

All of the outputs are saved in a folder named "WDAC" inside the current working directory.

**If you use the `-Deployit` optional switch parameter with the commands above, 3 things will automatically happen:**

1. The deployed Prep mode base policy will be removed.
2. The actual base policy will be deployed depending on whichever you choose.
3. The Supplemental policy generated from Audit logs will be deployed.

If you don't use the `-Deployit` switch, you can deploy the `.cip` binary files manually using [CITool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/operations/citool-commands).

[More info on deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/windows-defender-application-control-deployment-guide)

[**Information about how to Sign and Deploy a Signed WDAC policy.**](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/How-to-Create-and-Deploy-a-Signed-WDAC-Policy-Windows-Defender-Application-Control)